# Understanding Express routing in conjunction with AngularJS (using mean.js boilerplate)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am developing a web application with the mean.js boilerplate code. Recently I added a view to my application (the 'analysis' page) by creating an analysis module and added some route logic with the following code.

```
//Setting up route
angular.module('analysis').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        // Projects state routing
        $stateProvider.
        state('imageAnalysis', {
            url: '/image_analysis',
            templateUrl: 'modules/analysis/views/tools.client.view.html'
        });
    }
]);
```

This works just dandy, I can go to homepage.com/image_analysis and see my tools.client.view.html page. 
**My goal** now is to have this page only visible to user who are logged in. My first approach to this was to check if the user was logged in the angular routes logic, this has proven to be difficult for me. I also read that check authentication in the front end is very unsafe. So I've decided to check if the user is logged in with Express routing. 
Here is an example of what Express routing looks like for one of my other AngularJS modules

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');
    var projects = require('../../app/controllers/projects.server.controller');

    // Projects Routes
    app.route('/projects')
        .get(users.requiresLogin, projects.list)
        .post(users.requiresLogin, projects.create);

    app.route('/projects/:projectId')
        .get(users.requiresLogin, projects.read)
        .put(users.requiresLogin, projects.hasAuthorization, projects.update)
        .delete(users.requiresLogin, projects.hasAuthorization, projects.delete);

    // Finish by binding the Project middleware
    app.param('projectId', projects.projectByID);
};
```

Notice the users.requiresLogin function which check if a user is logged in and redirects the user to the signin page if they are not. I want to take advantage of this function. Some things I dont quite understand in the boilerplate code are **what is the purpose of app.route()?** I think this might be a middleware but I am not sure what it does.

Here are some attempts I've take taken at messing around with express routing. These attempts are in my analysis.server.routes.js file that I created.
Attempt 1

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');

    // analysis routes
    app.get('/image_analysis', function(req, res) {
        console.log('helloworld');
        console.log('helloworld');
        console.log('helloworld');
        console.log('helloworld');
        console.log('helloworld');
        console.log('helloworld');

    });
};
```

I thought this would log  'helloworld' when I access the image_analysis page, but it didnt appear to do anything. 
Attempt 2

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');

    // analysis routes
    app.route('/image_analysis')
        .get(users.requiresLogin);
};
```

Based on the other code, I thought this might work to require login for the analysis page. But it did nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks everyone, I am struggling to grasp express routing at the moment and stackoverflow has been a tremendous help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution, or not at least at this moment that I could think of.
However I can explain to you how things work and why a solution might not be trivial.

---

> what is the purpose of `app.route()`

This defines your routes.

```
app.route('/projects/:projectId')
    .get(users.requiresLogin, projects.read)
    .put(users.requiresLogin, projects.hasAuthorization, projects.update)
    .delete(users.requiresLogin, projects.hasAuthorization, projects.delete);
```

What that code does is when a client requests a URL like one of the following

```
GET /projects/5562ff08de4f70180bba3083
PUT /projects/5562ff08de4f70180bba3083
DELETE /projects/5562ff08de4f70180bba3083
```

it first executes that middleware function `users.requiresLogin`,
which is defined to be common in all methods (`.get` `.put` `.delete`)
and then their respective middlewares in that order 
`projects.read` | `projects.hasAuthorization` ...

On how [Angluar routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) works in contrast to Express routing:
Angluar routing is all done client-side. It's all achieved through Javascript
changing the addressbar url and displaying the view attached to that route.

Your Angular app is served by the server through a single (Express) route - `/` (homepage)

So again, your entire Angular app loads thorough just 1 route on the server-side,
and then Angular takes over the routing to client-side through it's own [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

Now it must be starting to seem obvious that it's not trivial to have server-side authentication check
interfere between client-side routing.

You can only have server-side authentication work with routes that server actually is in control of serving.
Those are mostly just your API routes, in your case.

---

> Attempt 1
>
> ```
> app.get('/image_analysis', function(req, res) {
>     console.log('helloworld');
> ```
>
> I thought this would log 'helloworld' when I access the image_analysis page, but it didnt appear to do anything.

It indeed should have! Unless.. there's a route that comes before it that already serves all requests

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.send(angularApp); // your angular app is served here
});

// No request would *need* to go beyond past this point
// because it already got served above

app.get('/image_analysis', function(req, res) {
    // so this isn't reached.
    console.log('helloworld');
});
```

So that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I dont see anything that looks like this in my code `app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.send(angularApp); // your angular app is served here
});`

Comment: @DanielJacobson I see. You're using this [meanjs boilerplate](https://github.com/meanjs/mean)? And you stored your `analysis.server.routes.js` in `/app/routes/`? It *should* work then…

Comment: Yes. Im currently trying to create an angular service factory to access the express routes but theres no data I want to post or get, I just want express to console log